# java: calling a method

Tags: java, methods, subroutine

I am just learning how to create a subroutine/method in java, and I am having the problem that I can't call my method with the compiler thinking that my call (playGame();) is an attempted definition of a method of itself. So i get the error "invalid method declaration; return type required". As I am a beginner I am sure that it is a stupid mistake, but I have tried rewriting many times to fix it and I cannot figure it out.

```
public class GUI {  
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
    public static void playGame() {

    }
    playGame();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call a method from within another method, not from the body of a class. Move the line

```
playGame();
```

inside the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    playgame();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method call should be inside another method , in this case `main` (or) You can call from `playGame()` also, but that would be `recursion` and may end up in `infinite loop.`

```
public static void main(String[] args){

playGame();
}
```

See [Essentials of the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html) to learn more about how to write java program.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call methods from class body directly the way you are doing. You need to call method `playGame()` from main method. Like :

```
public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       playGame();
    }
    public static void playGame() {
       // some  statements
    }    
}
```

As you are new Start Reading [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).